# How to get GAID Avertising ID?

Tags: flutter, dart

How could I read the GAID of a user in a Flutter application? I only found [this](https://pub.dev/packages/advertising_id) package but it isn't well supported and it is not null-safe. Is there any native solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/advertising_id)?

You can simply do:

```
dependencies:
  advertising_id: ^2.4.0
```

and

```
try {
      advertisingId = await AdvertisingId.id(true);
    } on PlatformException {
      advertisingId = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
```

Works for me to retrieve the Google Advertising ID (GAID).

Otherwise I don't think there is any other way right now to do it except for bare bone Android development.

Comment: I tried it but it seems an unofficial plugin and it doesn't support null-safety.

Comment: I dont think there is currently any other possibility except for accessing the value via Android functions. See: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id